# MySQL get previous day data

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have the following table

```
Date       | amount 1    | 
-----------|-------------|
2020-01-01 | 100         | 
2020-01-02 | 120         | 
2020-01-03 | 150         |
```

What I try to get is writing the day before data on the following day

```
Date       | amount 1    | amount 2 |
-----------|-------------|----------|
2020-01-01 | 100         | 0        |
2020-01-02 | 120         | 100      |
2020-01-03 | 150         | 120      |
```

I can get yesterday but don't know how to do it for all rows.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: it seems that the version I run is 5.6.28-76.1-56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next approach.

```
select 
    test.date1, 
    test.amount1,  
    ifnull(yestarday_test.amount1, 0) as amount2
from test
left join test yestarday_test on 
    date_sub(yestarday_test.date1, interval -1 day ) = test.date1
order by test.date1 asc
;
```

In this query we use join same table to itself by date with 1 day shift.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vDR154LCC3ECcpLr6HLZWg/1)

Comment: It worked but I had to remove the ifnull section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select date, amount,
       lag(amount, 1, 0) over (order by date) as amount_prev
from t;
```

Comment: can you explain what the `lag` function is? I've never heard of it before. Cheers

Comment: @Martin . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL < 8.0, where window functions are not available, one option is a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    date,
    amount,
    (
        select t1.amount 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.date < t.date 
        order by t1.date desc limit 1
    ) prev_amount
from mytable t
```